# Convert MS Access .mdb database files to alternative formats for work under Linux?

Tags: convert, linux, ms-access

For a long time, I am struggling with .mdb databases I receive for my work under Linux (especially with QGIS). Even from within Access on Windows, I found no convenient way to export the whole database, but only an export to separate .csv files, which is tedious and stupid.

There are online converters available, but they all have a limit in upload size around 50MB, so most of my databases do not fit.

Other proposals were to connect via ODBC or convert via JAVA libraries, but both ways were too complicated or failed for me.

Comment: as the old saying goes - "I wouldn't start from there"

Comment: @IanTurton I'm not that good with english saying ... so from where should I start then?

Comment: don't store your data in access :-) If you can find (or build) a java included version of GDAL/OGR you could use https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mdb.html#vector-mdb

Comment: haha, good one. It's not me storing this stuff in mdb, but the dudes at our governmental agencies. Good to know about the GDAL stuff, but I rather prefer not building things myself under Linux, I just use it for comfortability reasons ;)

Comment: Some scripting using mdbtools package executables (`apt install mdbtools`). List tables with `mdb-tables`, dump table(s) schema to sqlite or postgresql with `mdb-schema` and use `mdb-export` to export content tables to SQL statements. Add some glue and done. PS: fine for non geospatial but OGR/GDAL better way if geospatial content. See https://gist.github.com/mywarr/9908044 or https://gist.github.com/kazlauskis/1d0bdb9efb3b1bb1e76d48aa368f3a64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script in **R** for converting MS Access **.mdb** files to SQLite.
It is using the Hmisc library for reading and RSqlite package for writing to a **.sqlite** file, which performs well in QGIS under Linux.

```r
library(Hmisc) #for "mdb.get"
library(RSQLite) # for export to sqlite
library(tidyverse) # for "mutate_if"

# Path to .mdb:
mdb_path <-"/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xyz.mdb" # <- Adjust path to file here

# create variables for path, filename etc. for export
dest_path <- dirname(mdb_path) #dirname from base; Change, if result should go to another directory than the source
dest_name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(mdb_path)) # file name without extension. Change if result name should be different

## load mdb
# create list of mdb-tables
lst.MDB <- list()
# populate list with data frames from mdb-tables
lst.MDB <- mdb.get(mdb_path,allow="_") # allow="_" preventing transformation from underscore to point
# transform factors to character with mutate_if
lst.MDB <- lapply(lst.MDB ,function(x) mutate_if(x,is.factor, as.character))

# create list of table names from the list of data frames
lst.MDB.names <- as.list(names(lst.MDB))
#create connection to new sqlite database
db = dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname= paste(dest_path,paste(dest_name, ".sqlite",sep=""),sep="/"))

# loop over table names
for(i in lst.MDB.names){
  dbWriteTable( #from RSqlite : https://rdrr.io/cran/RSQLite/man/dbWriteTable.html
    db, # connection
    i, # table name
    lst.MDB[[i]], # data frame form list of data frames
    field.types = NULL,
    overwrite = TRUE,
    append = FALSE,
    header = TRUE,
    colClasses = NA,
    row.names = FALSE,
    nrows = 50,
    sep = ",",
    eol = "\n",
    skip = 0,
    temporary = FALSE
  )                                            
}

#UPDATE: alternatively writing to GeoPackage using library sf

#write data tables to gpkg: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388760/8202
library(sf)
for(i in lst.MDB.names){
  st_write(lst.MDB[[i]],
           paste(dest_path,paste(dest_name, ".gpkg",sep=""),sep="/"),
           layer = i)                                         
}
#Done
```